# Probability That the Sides of an Isosceles Triangle is an Equilateral Triangle

Tags: probability

The sides of an isosceles triangle are whole numbers, and its perimeter is 30 units. What is the probability that the triangle is equilateral?

I'm thinking that I should use Geometric Probability, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Without a probability distribution or a process for generating sides, one can't answer this with certainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ denote the lengths of the sides of our triangle. Without loss of generality, since the triangle is isoceles, let $a=c$, so that $(a,a,b)$ describes our triangle, where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$. Now we know additionally $2a+b=30$, and by the triangle inequality, $b\leq 2a$, So $30-2a\leq 2a$, i.e. $a \geq 8$, but of course $a\leq 15$. Thus the possible triangles are described by $\{(8,8,14),(9,9,12),(10,10,10),(11,11,8),(12,12,6),(13,13,4),(14,14,2),(15,15,0)\}$. Only one of these is equilateral. Now assuming uniform distribution over these possibilities, and depending whether you include the degenerate $(15,15,0)$, the probability is either $1\over 7$ or $1\over 8$.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't a lot of options. There is only one equilateral triangle, which has side length (10,10,10).
In order to form a triangle, the sum of any two sides needs to be larger than the third side, so only these combinations are possible: (14,14,2),(13,13,4),(12,12,6),(11,11,8),(10,10,10),(9,9,12),(8,8,14)
So the answer is $\frac17$

Comment: You're implicitly assuming a uniform distribution over the possible cases.