# What percentage of the set of all possible triangles is equilateral?

Tags: geometry

I’m not even certain that this is a meaningful question.  If we somehow start generating random triangles, as the number approaches infinity, what faction of them will be equilateral, isosceles or scalene?

Comment: Yes, the question is meaningful. What is the probability that a given triangle is equilateral? Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810127/probability-that-the-sides-of-an-isosceles-triangle-is-an-equilateral-triangle) and search for duplicates first.

Comment: The answer will depend on specific "somehow" realization?

Comment: I appreciate the responses, though I’m not clear that the question I’m referred to addresses the question I asked.

Comment: Let me try to clarify.  If we randomly generate 1,000, or 1,000,000, or a trillion trillion triangles, what percentage would be equilateral (or isosceles, or scalene)?